# Operation Failure : Not authorized on aggregations to execute the command

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

I am new to the mongodb , and i have been learning some of the methods using the pymongo version 3.8.0 and the jupyter notebook. It has been going fine, until i tried the **"$lookup"** methods, now it has started throwing the error 
**Operations Failure: not authorized on aggregations to execute the command**. Any help/suggestions on solving the issue will highly be appreciated.

I have tried reinstalling the packages, and enable windows administration privileges, that so far has not solved the problem

```
OperationFailure: not authorized on aggregations to execute command 
{ aggregate: "air_routes", pipeline: [ { $match: { airplane: { $regex: "747|380" } } }, { $lookup: { from: "air_alliance", localField: "airline.name", foreignField: "airlines", as: "data_src" } }, 
{ $unwind: "$data_src" }, { $group: { _id: { name: "$name", airlines: "$airlines" }, numberofflights: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $sort: { numberofflights: -1 } }, 
{ allowDiskUse: true } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("af942a3d-309b-4cd2-a99b-3ebcd60406f4") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1557101096, 1), 
signature: { hash: BinData(0, AD50B7BE136F58D794C75C6AD031E92168EF61D1), keyId: 6627672121604571137 } }, $db: "aggregations", $readPreference: { mode: "primary" } }
```

Please help resolve this issue. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i have found the answer, apparently, it is permissions related issue, and the second call to the database (databases are stored on atlas cluster) was passing some parameters (apparently), which were either coming off empty or were not fetched properly, reasons for which are still not clear. Therefore, the second collection set "air_alliance" was reproducing the error.

A helpful thread is given here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1722